# Is it possible to store the whole line in a variable while using awk?

Tags: awk

How can I store the whole line in a variable?

example

```
    awk ' 
/hello.*/ {line= something??}
' abc.txt
```

Comment: As an aside, the `.*` in your pattern is totally useless and can be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '/hello/{line=$0}' abc.txt
```

this is what you need =)